# Heckman's two stage: multiple selection models

Tags: regression

If a sample is likely to be self-selected on multiple selection criteria, does it make sense to include Inverse Mill's ratios for multiple selection models in the same second stage OLS model?

Answer (score 1):

In such a case, it depends on the specific case you are trying to understand. You can refer to Wooldridge's book "Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data, 2nd Edition" for detailed discussion. It suggests that preferably IM should be used at both stages.